# Convert html source code to json object

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am fetching html source code of many pages from one website, I need to convert it into json object and combine with other elements in json doc. . I have seen many questions on same topic but non of them were helpful.

My code:

```
url = "https://totalhash.cymru.com/analysis/?1ce201cf28c6dd738fd4e65da55242822111bd9f"
htmlContent = requests.get(url, verify=False)
data = htmlContent.text
print("data",data)
jsonD = json.dumps(htmlContent.text)
jsonL = json.loads(jsonD)

ContentUrl='{ \"url\" : \"'+str(urls)+'\" ,'+"\n"+' \"uid\" : \"'+str(uniqueID)+'\" ,\n\"page_content\" : \"'+jsonL+'\" , \n\"date\" : \"'+finalDate+'\"}'
```

above code gives me unicode type, however, when I put that output in jsonLint it gives me invalid json error. Can somebody help me understand how can I convert the complete html into a json objet?

Comment: try using flask modules jsonify() method.

Comment: The source of the url does not returns json. To fetch element values from HTML, you need to use something like BeautifulSoup or lxml, etc

Comment: You are doing some very strange things here. Why would you dump to JSON, then immediately load, and *then* build up a JSON string manually?

Comment: @SatishGarg I am using beautiful soup for further processings but there I am trying to save the original html as well.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am quite new to this so did not have much of an idea what I am doing I was just trying to make in json format.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`jsonD = json.dumps(htmlContent.text)` converts the raw HTML content into a JSON string representation.
`jsonL = json.loads(jsonD)` parses the JSON string back into a regular string/unicode object. This results in a no-op, as any escaping done by `dumps()` is reverted by `loads()`. `jsonL` contains the same data as `htmlContent.text`.

Try to use `json.dumps` to generate your final JSON instead of building the JSON by hand:

```
ContentUrl = json.dumps({
    'url': str(urls),
    'uid': str(uniqueID),
    'page_content': htmlContent.text,
    'date': finalDate
})
```

Comment: It worked like charm. Thanks for making my understanding better as well. I clicked on accept answer, but have no idea why it is not working

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to convert HTML source code to a JSON file on the local system is as follows:

```
import json
import codecs

# Load the JSON file by specifying the location and filename
with codecs.open(filename="json_file.json", mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as jsonf:
    json_file = json.loads(jsonf.read())

# Load the HTML file by specifying the location and filename
with codecs.open(filename="html_file.html", mode='r', encoding="utf-8") as htmlf:
    html_file = htmlf.read()

# Chose the key name where the HTML source code will live as a string
json_file['Key1']['Key2'] = html_file

# Dump the dictionary to JSON object and save it in a specific location 
json_object = json.dumps(json_file, indent=4)
with codecs.open(filename="final_json_file.json", mode="w", encoding="utf-8") as ojsonf:
    ojsonf.write(json_object)
```

- Next, open the JSON file in your editor.
- Press CTRL + H, and replace \n or \t characters by '' (nothing!).
- Now you can parse your HTML file with codecs.open() function and do the operations.