# How to export entire body of HTML to nested JSON

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am using Python3 and Scrapy.

I have a simple spider (shown bellow) for which I want to save as items the `response.url` and the `response.text`. I would like to save the `response.text` to Notepad++ as a JSON. Is there any way it can be saved with a nested structure? Such as the one that appears in the native HTML og the page?

```
class Spider1(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Spider1"
    allowed_domains = []
    start_urls = ['http://www.uam.es/']    

    def parse(self, response):
        items = Spider1Item()
        items['url'] = response.url
        items['body'] = response.text
        yield items

        pass
```

EDIT:
Here is a snippet of the target structure I would like when I export to a JSON.
[HTML snippet of target structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJmpV.png)

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking. If `json.loads()` works, then you (probably) already have a nested structure (which is JSON, not HTML). Also, by "saving to Notepad++", do you just mean a text file?

Comment: Let me try to explain more clearly... Originally I did not have `json.loads()`, thus `items['body']` is as reflected above. My idea is to save `response.body` as a JSON in Notepad++, which I have achieved. The issue is that it is saved as a string, and not as a nested HTML like it appears in the original web source. What I would like is that each `items['body']` saves `response.text` as a nested HTML in my JSON, for later parsing and post-processing.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by nexted HTML. Could you provide a short snippet that shows an example of the expected output?

Comment: @Gallaecio I have edited my post and attached an image of my target structure when exporting to JSON

Comment: In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43469412/convert-html-source-code-to-json-object) question @umesh-kaushik suggest this `jsonD = json.dumps(response.text) `

Comment: @NandoQuintana The resource you pointed to is very useful, but it doesn't quite do what I am looking for. Maybe I will post-process the html to recreate its original nested form.

Comment: Scrapy does not provide such a feature built-in, and I do not think it will ever do, as it goes beyond scraping itself. You should remove the Scrapy references from your question (title, description, tags, code snippet) to reach a wider audience here in StackOverflow. You are looking for a Python library or code snippet that transforms an HTML input (string) into a JSON-renderizable data structure.

Comment: I do wonder… Why do you want to do that? What do you want to achieve in the end? If you want the page contents in a readable format, wouldn’t it be better to simply lint them with something in the lines of https://pypi.org/project/html-linter/ ?

Comment: @Gallaecio I am looking to apply an NLP algorithm in post-processing, but I need the HTML structure as it appears on the webpage, not in linear format as when it is exported to JSON. I will look at the resource you pointed out and see if I can use it.