# Python convert HTML table to json

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am having a html table like this. tried using pandas.read_html and beautifulsoup,. really frustrating, help please!!

here is my original python code:

```
url = 'http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/keystatsAjax.html?t=wja&culture=en-CA&region=CAN'
lm_json = requests.get(url).json()
ksContent = BeautifulSoup(lm_json["ksContent"],"html.parser")
table = ksContent.find("table", {'class': "r_table1 text2"})
jsonD = json.dumps(table.text)
jsonL = json.loads(jsonD)
```

the 'table' will have the html table, but the json conversion makes a pure text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert html source code to json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43469412/convert-html-source-code-to-json-object)

Comment: I have the code updated, but the json conversion gives pure text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jsonD = json.dumps(htmlContent.text)` converts the raw HTML content into a JSON string representation. `jsonL = json.loads(jsonD)` parses the JSON string back into a regular string/unicode object. This results in a no-op, as any escaping done by `dumps()` is reverted by `loads()`. `jsonL` contains the same data as `htmlContent.text`.

Comment: I uploaded the codes , but the json.dump produces pure text

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using python pandas:

```
first_table = result.find("table")
df = pd.read_html(str(first_table))

with open("./table.json", "a+") as f:
    f.write(df[0].to_json(orient='records'))
    f.close()
```

working for me.