# how to convert html file to json using python

Tags: python, html, json

i want to fetch html file from some location and convert it to Json format using python.

for below code i m getting output just a text.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
html = '<p>Hello</p><p>world</p>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
things = soup.find_all(text=True)
print(things)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 jsonD = json.dumps(htmlContent.text) converts the raw HTML content into a JSON 
 string representation. jsonL = json.loads(jsonD) parses the JSON string back into a 
 regular string/unicode object. This results in a no-op, as any escaping done by 
 dumps() is reverted by loads(). jsonL contains the same data as htmlContent.text.

 Try to use json.dumps to generate your final JSON instead of building the JSON by 
 hand:

 ContentUrl = json.dumps({
'url': str(urls),
'uid': str(uniqueID),
'page_content': htmlContent.text,
'date': finalDate
})
```

Comment: this answer seems to be directly lifted from  here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43469412/convert-html-source-code-to-json-object

Comment: Yes coz of the issue is same and working so what's wrong in that @mohan111

Comment: most of the users avoid the open link so it's better you can suggest directly  that's  why I did it @mohan111