# Can we convert any HTML Table Data to Json file ? I want to save the data of HTML Table to the Json file Can we?

Tags: angular7

I want to convert the HTML page table or any data to save into the JSON file like  we have the data of student with id, school name, class, Mother name, father's name etc and I want to convert that data to the JSON file can we if yes please give me the answer or any hint what you think about this problem I need a help

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43469412/convert-html-source-code-to-json-object/43469641

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Table to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271856/html-table-to-json)