# Using the content of an HTML file in a JSON string in shell or Makefile (AWS)

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell, makefile, aws-cli

I am attempting to use the AWS apigateway CLI to set an Integration Response mapping template for one of my endpoints in my API. This particular case involves using text/html as my Content-Type and as such my mapping template is raw HTML code. Depending on certain circumstances, I would like to use the CLI to set the mapping template to different HTML code. As such, I am attempting to read the HTML content from a specified file into the `--response-template` JSON string, which will fill in the mapping template.

The command to do this is as follows:

```
aws apigateway put-integration-response 
   --rest-api-id $(restApiId) --resource-id $(resourceId) \
   --http-method POST --status-code 200 \
   --selection-pattern "" \
   --response-parameters '{"method.response.header.Content-Type":"'"'"'text/html'"'"'"}' \
   --response-templates '{"text/html": "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><body><p>Hello, world</p></body></html>"}'
```

I was originally attempting to do this in a Makefile, hence the variables, but I am open to creating a shell script to achieve the same thing. My HTML file is much larger than the example above and contains scripts with functions, brackets, JSON objects, plenty of strings to stylesheets and whatnot - in other words, many characters that need to be escaped. I cannot manually change the HTML file nor am I sure if I can modify it with escape characters since the mapping template needs to be the exact HTML content as that is what is being rendered.

Is it possible for me to place the entire contents of an HTML file into the value portion of that JSON string? If so, how can I get this to work?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not have a Lambda return the HTML? Why use API Gateway for an HTML page? Or serve the HTML from a S3 static website?

Comment: The HTML page that I am trying to render is receiving parameters from a POST request that is hitting a small Lambda function that echos back the form data in a JSON structure, which allows the Velocity mapping template to place it into the HTML. The parameters it places into the file are placed in a variable in a script that then gets used to compute an extensive Lambda function. I am not using a Lambda function to load the whole page as it is saving execution time, since the extensive Lambda that runs after page render takes a while to load the data that it is fetching.

Comment: I'm aware that this is not the most ideal way of doing things but I am transitioning an old Play! Framework application to work with AWS and this is one of the wacky things that I have come across.

Comment: I see. Have you tried putting the json in a file and referencing it as --response-templates file://yourfile.json. I can't confirm if this works, but different CLI commands support file references.

Comment: I have not tried that, but I have found a solution using Python. I will post it as the answer to this question.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simon offered a possible solution to this while using the AWS CLI approach but I have solved this in another way.

I decided to use a Python script with the AWS Python SDK, [Boto3](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/). I used Python's `json` library to dump the content of the HTML file into valid JSON format using `json.dumps()`. I put that as the value to the JSON object that eventually was used in the Boto3 function below and did an inline replacement of the value as I sent it with `json.loads()`. I followed the top answer from this link on how to [convert html source code to json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43469412/convert-html-source-code-to-json-object).

I used the Boto3 [`put_integration_response()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#APIGateway.Client.put_integration_response) function and sent that JSON object as the `--response-template`, which worked for me.